# Ajuda com as "tabs" do jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Olá, estou precisando de uma ajuda com as `tabs` do `jQuery UI`

segue o
[EXEMPLO](http://codepen.io/furlann/pen/QNmdoQ)

No caso,precisava que as `subCategorias` ficassem "escondidas" e quando clicar na "Categoria" pai as `subCategorias` apareçam.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz umas pequenas modificações no teu script.
http://codepen.io/vitorandre/pen/KzomxM

Seguinte:
Adicione um ID na li da categoria. Usei Cat1.
Ponha no css um display:none na .liCategoria
No jquery acrescente uma função que altera o css.

Comment: obrigado @Vitor deu certo!